# yii 2 date picker only allow before today

Tags: php, yii, datepicker, yii2

```
echo $form->field($model, 'dob')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
  'options' => [
    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Please pick your birth-date'), 
  ],
  'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
  'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    'startView' => 1,
  ],
])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Date of Birth'));
```

The code above is used  to create a DatePicker in yii 2. Is it possible for me to only allow users to select date before today?

Comment: which date picker your are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can the future dates disable by `endDate` property of `pluginOptions`.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'dob')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
  'options' => [
    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Please pick your birth-date'), 
  ],
  'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
  'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    'startView' => 1,
    'endDate'=>date('d/m/Y')
  ],
])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Date of Birth'));
```